# Unable to find javac after installing OpenJDK 1.6 and 1.7

Tags: linux, java

I am currently at a loss as to why this is happening.

I did some basic research by running:

```
# whereis javac
```

and

```
# find / -name javac
```

...and I came up with nothing.

I searched the web for answers but they all seem to focus on `javac` existing on the filesystem, and that needs to be done is to restore a missing symlink.

Has anyone run up against this issue and found a solution?

I have attempted to install openJDK on Scientific Linux 6.3 with the command:

```
# yum install openjdk
```

Answer (score 2):

You actually just need to install `java-[version]-openjdk-devel`, because the base package doesn't include compilers or other developer tools. This contains `/usr/lib/jvm/java-[version]-openjdk-[version].[arch]/bin/javac`, and will use the *alternatives* system to set up a symlink to `/usr/bin/javac`.

Comment: Someone needs to tell the package maintainers what the 'd' stands for in 'jdk'!

Answer (score 0):

```
javac: Command not found
```

If you receive this error, UNIX cannot find the compiler, javac.

Here's one way to tell UNIX where to find javac. Suppose you installed the JDK in `/usr/local/jdk1.8.0`. At the prompt you would type the following command and press Return:

```
/usr/local/jdk1.8.0/javac hello.java
```

Note: If you choose this option, each time you compile or run a program, you'll have to precede your javac and java commands with `/usr/local/jdk1.8.0/`. To avoid this extra typing, you could add this information to your PATH variable. The steps for doing so will vary depending on which shell you are currently running.

Class names, 'hello', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested

If you receive this error, you forgot to include the .java suffix when compiling the program. Remember, the command is javac hello.java not javac hello.

For more details, consult this lecture "Creating a Hello World application" in this page. http://learnjavaeasy.com/course/learn-java-online-with-java-8-by-examples/

Answer (score 0):

install developer tools e.g if you are using 1.7 RHEL install
yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel and this will install javac

Answer (score -1):

Yum list openjdk to make sure the file is in the rpm then you can run yum whatprovides *\javac to see all packages that contain the binary.

Comment: `yum list` doesn't do what you think it does. `yum provides` is a good suggestion, though.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried making a softlink from the library utility location to your terms or bin dir?
Have you tried?

```
grep -r javac /usr/jdk
```

Answer (score -1):

Javac is not included in the OpenJDK package.  You will need the JDK package from Oracle in order to get that, and other, executable java programs.